# How to execute lua bytecode genrated by luac on linux

Tags: linux, lua, bytecode

I have a simple lua source code called hello.lua

```
print('Hello Lua')
```

I complied this file to bytecode on a RedHat Linux machine , using Lua5.3.4 as follows:

```
luac -o hello.luac  hello.lua
chmod +x hello.luac
./hello.luac 
bash: ./hello.luac: cannot execute binary file
```

The architecture should be fine I guess. I cant figure what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precompiled Lua programs are run exactly the same way as source:

```
lua hello.luac
```

Comment: does `luac` still support a shebang? The [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7) states that the interpreter does, but a [quick search](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-05/msg00552.html) seems like this may have been dropped for `luac` in Lua 5.2.

Comment: @Adam, yes, it does in 5.2+.

Comment: @lhf  That works! That was easy. I was under the assumption that it should work as a binary without any interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

The shebang is removed by luac even if the lua source file has it.  In some case when it's necessary to run the compiled binary without any parameter, e.g. CGI, you can add the shebang manually at the top of the luac file:

```
luac -o hello.luac hello.lua
echo '#!/usr/bin/env lua' > shebang
cat shebang hello.luac > hello.luac2
mv hello.luac2 hello.luac
chmod +x hello.luac
./hello.luac
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lhf states in his answer Lua byte code is executed using the Lua interpreter, and as the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7) suggests:

> To allow the use of Lua as a script interpreter in Unix systems, the standalone interpreter skips the first line of a chunk if it starts with #. Therefore, Lua scripts can be made into executable programs by using `chmod +x` and the `#!` form.

Add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
print('Hello Lua')
```